# Como envio el valor de una variable desde el main a una funcion o public static void en C#?

Tags: c#, consola

Como envio el valor de una variable desde el main a una funcion o public static void en C#?

```
    using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Suma(){
        //Que la suma la haga aca enviando los valores introducidos desde el main...
        int SumaTotal = A + B;
    }
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            int A;
            Console.Write("                 ¿Valor de A?:  ");
            A = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int B;
            Console.Write("                 ¿Valor de B?:  ");
            B = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        //Y que aca me de la suma pero no hacerla en el main...
        Suma();
    }

}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es enviar datos desde el main y que se guarden para usarlos en una funcion o void.... total, nose como hacerlo y busco ayuda.

y el resultado imprimirlo en el main.

Comment: ¿Quieres [pasar parámetros](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es mandarlo como parametros, eso es lo que te falta. Un método puede recibir variables a las que denominamos parametros, dichos elementos puedes usarlos dentro del método, depende de ti si los devuelves o no.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static int Suma(int A, int B){
        return A + B;
    }
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            int A;
            Console.Write("                 ¿Valor de A?:  ");
            A = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int B;
            Console.Write("                 ¿Valor de B?:  ");
            B = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        int sumaTotal = Suma(a, b);//Asignamos el retorno para usarlo
        Console.WriteLine(sumaTotal);
    }

}
```

`void` en tus métodos indica que no devuelves nada, por eso no es requerido el return, sin embargo, como quieres imprimirlo en Main, necesitas devolver la suma, dicha suma que realizas es de int(numeros enteros). Pero perfectamente puedes hacer métodos de cualquier tipo de variable

```
public static <tipo> <nombre>(<parametros>){
//Lógica
}
```

---

Donde;
`<tipo>`: Es el tipo de variable que quieres retornar, tales como string, int, bool, double, etc... En caso de que solo quieras procesar algo y no retornar nada, usas `void` justamente como lo tienes actualmente
`<nombre>`: Es el nombre del método, preferiblemente ponle alguno relacionado a lo que haces adentro, por ejemplo, tu método suma dos numeros, ponle *Suma* o algo por el estilo
`<parametros>`: Son todas las variables que quieres manipular dentro de tu método, deben de ir indicadas que tipo son, podemos recibir n cantidad de variables y tipos

---

Para invocar tu método, solo asegurate que esté dentro de tu clase

```
public class program {
//Aqui dentro
}
```

Para poderlas llamar de la siguiente manera

```
mimétodo();
```

*Recuerda! Si retornas algo, es porque lo quieres usar, por lo que asignalo a una variable como te lo coloqué en tu código.

Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

El **método Main**, es un miembro de la **clase Program**, así que perfectamente puedes crear propiedades y atributos a nivel de clase y hacer lo q deseas

```
public class Program
{
   int a = 0;
   int b = 0;

   //Y aquí vendría la declaración del método Main y los métodos declarados por ti
}
```